# Enable php extension for installation Magento2 on Xampp

Tags: magento2, php-7

I am trying to install **Magento2** on **Xampp** and got some **php** **extensions errors** that are **not enables**. Please help me to enable these enable following **php** extensions.

1. PHP Extension xsl.
2. PHP Extension intl.
3. PHP Extension soap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Check `php.ini` file. This is normally under your xampp folder (Example   `D:\xampp\php`)
2. Search like `php_soap.dll;`,`php_xsl.dll`,`php_intl.dll` each dll extension
3. removing the first ; character, to make it looks like

> extension=php_soap.dll
>
> extension=php_xsl.dll
>
> extension=php_intl.dll

4. Once done restart Apache server.

Comment: is it works on mac os? I tried. but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Open your Php.ini file available at the location **`{your_installation_drive}:\xampp\php`**

Search for the below given extension over there.

```
extension=intl.dll

extension=php_soap.dll

extension=php_xsl.dll
```

May be available at line no **`884, 906 & 911`** respectively just remove the **`;`** symbol before the extensions.

Save the **`php.ini`** file & restart the the server again

If still facing the same problem feel free to revert

Thank you!